# Getting xr and xr-hyper to ignore the bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, xr

Now that `xr` and `xr-hyper` allow `\cite` to refer to `\bibitem`s in the external document, is there a way to get these packages to *ignore* the `\bibitem`s of the external document? In other words, is there an easy way to get these packages to work as they did before?

I have two documents connected with `\externaldocument`, but they each have their own bibliography, with some overlap in the `\bibitem`s. So as of now I get a number of messages about multiply-defined labels when I compile these documents. Sort of like this:

```
%%%doc1.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper,hyperref}
\externaldocument{doc2}
\begin{document}
\section{}\label{sec1}
\ref{secA}
\cite{1}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
%%%doc2.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper,hyperref}
\externaldocument{doc1}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\section{}\label{secA}
\ref{sec1}
\cite{1}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{1}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

This was not a problem before `xr` and `xr-hyper` allowed `\cite` to refer to `\bibitem`s in the external document. In fact, in my much longer and more complex real documents, the `\cite` commands sometimes print the numbers of the `\bibitem`s in the other document, but I can't reproduce that here.

As of now, the simplest way I can see to cure this problem is to change the names of the `\bibitem`s and the `\cite` commands to them in one of the documents, but that will be very tedious given the size of these documents.

Comment: `\externaldocument[][nocite]{somefile}` should work, I think...

Comment: That does seem to work in my test files above.